# Firebase cloud firestore is storing document reference as string not as object reference

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection campgrounds which should store the references of the comment documents as an array of object reference
I did it like this

```
try {
    commentRef.add(newComment).then(ref => {
        console.log("success COMMENT ADDED");
        var refForThisComment = ref.id;
        docRef.update({
            comments: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                "/campgrounds/" + refForThisComment
            )
        });
        res.redirect("/campgrounds");
    });
} catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
}
```

But in the console when I check the document reference array is a string array!

Comment: What exactly are you expecting that code to do instead?  Please be specific about the outcome.

Comment: The comment array looks like this [link](https://ibb.co/g4fGbcJ) so instead of this it should say reference so that i can refrence to that comment document later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing a string array because you passed a string to `arrayUnion`:

```
"/campgrounds/" + refForThisComment
```

This doesn't just become a document reference.  String concatenation always produces a string in JavaScript.

If you want a document reference, pass a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) object instead:

```
comments: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(ref)
```

Comment: I gave you the line of code to change in my answer.

Comment: The comment array still contains the refrence as a string [Check it out](https://ibb.co/h9GKbvw)         the code is `docRef.update({
                comments: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                    refForThisComment
                )
            });`

Comment: Sorry, use `ref` instead of `refForThisComment`, which is just a string id.